Moveit planning and collision with scene and objects
I'm new to ROS (noetic) and I'm working with a UR10 and a cell imported in stl and defined in collision in the URDF. For several days now, I've had a problem: when I move the robot in the scene, the collision is correctly detected, as you can see here:

When I move the robot through the scene, instead of avoiding it, it goes through it and collides with the scene :

I tried the same thing by adding a box to the scene and publishing it, with the same result.
Has anyone had this problem and can help me?
Thank you in advance, I haven't found much on the internet.
